# Flask. add() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a student making a simple wishlist website with user entered data through Flask and SQLalchemy. I've been struggling with this issue and many others ever since I added some new columns to my database. The user inputs the fields through an HTML form, the code of that can be found below.

```
    <form action="{{url_for('add')}}" method='POST'>
        <input type="text" name="content" id="content">
        <input type="text" name="link" id="link">
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Item"> <!--EndBlock Body-->

    </form>
```

When the user presses the submit button it runs the below code to add the user inputted feilds into my database, Content, price and link. but whatever I do it doesn't commit to my database and when it nearly does, it simply throws all of the user inputs into the content column in my database then throws an error (which is probably caused by my attempted workarounds of this problem)

````
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_content = request.form['content']
        item_price = request.form['price']
        item_link = request.form['link']

        try:             #Try to add new item and if fail return error message
        db.session.add(item_content, item_price, item_link) #add the column/row in db
        db.session.commit() #commit item to datebase
        return redirect('/index') #go back to main page
        except:
            return 'There was an Issue adding this item'```

Many Thanks!
````

Comment: It would be very helpful to see the terminal traceback with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue with some help from a friend.

```
@app.route("/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item_content = request.form.get('content')
        item_price = request.form.get('price')
        item_link = request.form.get('link')

        try:
            finalentry = wl(content = item_content, price = item_price , link = item_link) 
            db.session.add(finalentry) 
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/index') 
        except:
            return 'There was an Issue adding this item'
```

I fixed the issue by only adding a combined variable to the `db.session.add` instead of just adding them all as seperate variables. Not quite sure how this fixed my problem but I'll take the win. :>

Answer (score 0):

please try `request.form.get("<name_of_items")` rather than `request.form("<name_of_items")`.

and please change your flask function `add()` to anything else like : add_to_db().
it may cause confusion in the db.add().

Comment: I did the suggested changes and now get TypeError: "method" object is not subscriptable

Comment: are you sure u use `()` not use '[]' ?

Comment: correct form -- > tem_content = request.form.get('content')

Comment: Oops did not notice that at all haha. Now I'm back to my original error
```db.session.add(item_content, item_price, item_link)```